# Delete button for each table row

Tags: php, button

I manage to succesfully read and display data from my database with the following code:
http://pastebin.com/rjZfBWZX
I also generate a delete button for each row of the table :) Clicking the delete button calls  "obrisi.php" which is supposed to delete that row but I messed something up :S Here's obrisi.php  code:

http://pastebin.com/mrFy1i7S

I'm getting a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'FROM' (T_STRING) :S

Comment: 'id' column in my database is primary key and unique

Comment: Neither script produces a parse error like in your question.

Comment: As VolkerK says, can't see where your parse error might be... Although why all the white space? Clean up.

Comment: Sorry , i screwed something up :S
Im getting a new error now : Notice: Undefined index: id in G:\XAMP\xampp-port ... obrisi.php on line 54

I try to generate unique id for each delete button form with $id = $row['id'];   <input type='submit' id= '$id' . ' value='Delete' >" withing while loop but how do i access certain id values within obrisi.php ?  i tried  $id = $_GET['id'];  but im getting the error mentioned above :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's try and do it with _GET instead of _POST.

In your main code you need to change line 39 (the input) from:

```
    echo  "<td>" . " <input type='submit' id= '$id' . ' value='Delete' >" .  "</td>";
```

to:

```
    echo  "<td><a href='obrisi.php?id=$id'>Delete</a></td>";
```

In your obrisi.php change line 3 (the id setup) from:

```
    $id = $_POST['id'];
```

to:

```
    $id = $_GET['id'];
```

And finally as a nice addition, redirect back to the main page by adding the following line at the end of the obrisi.php file before the closing of the php tag.

```
    header('location:index.php');
```

Where index.php the name of the main page you have.

Comment: Of course you can do it with a button instead of a link by adding an onclick parameter to your button and there redirect with javascript to the correct url.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo  "<td>" . " <input type='submit' id= '$id' . ' value='Delete' >" .  "</td>";
```

some simple errors here. this would output (with $id = 1):

```
<td><input type='submit' id= '1' . ' value='Delete' ></td>
```

this line should be corrected to

```
    echo  '<td><input type="submit" id="' . $id . '" value="Delete" ></td>';
```

this is also going wrong.

```
echo "<form action="obrisi.php" method="post">";
```

should be like:

```
echo '<form action="obrisi.php" method="post">';
```

But the main problem is that there is no field id given in the post. The id of a html element is not sent on submit. it is basically to identify that element in the HTML structure.

And when using a submit button you will have to limit the scope of the form to that row and use a hidden input field, or use a link like thanpa suggests

to clarify: if you want to do it with a post (but i would sugget using the $_GET)

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) )
{

$id = $row['id'];

echo "<tr>";
echo '<form action="obrisi.php" method="post">';
echo "<td>" . $row['Ime'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Prezime'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Grad'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Drzava'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Obavijesti'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Tekst'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>"
echo  '<td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $id . '"/><input type="submit" value="Delete" ></td>';
echo "</form>
echo "</tr>";
}
```

and remove the echo's for the form from start and end of script.

Answer (score 1):

as an additional note here, if this is going to be at some point being used in a live system you need to be checking $id in obrisi.php that it is actually an ID and not something nasty and unexpected like more sql, look up sql injection.