# Delete button giving error but worked in other example

Tags: php, mysql, database, button

I followed this question to do a delete query [Delete button for each table row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191026/php-delete-button-for-each-table-row)

But I am having an issued with mine, this is the code for the main page http://pastebin.com/PEQAUJwF and this is the action page http://pastebin.com/ahTxKxSv

I don't know if it's because I listed the data differently or if my code is wrong. But it is listing the data from the database..

I am getting the error Database error! So it connects but it doesn't pass the query. BTW this is on my localhost.

Please can someone assist?

Comment: Please don't put code on external sites - inline the relevant parts in your question.

Comment: Sorry about that, will do next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to mention here database name.

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'adjudication', '', '') or die('Connection error!');
                                                       ^^^
```

should be

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'adjudication', '', 'your_db') or die('Connection error!');
```

Comment: Ugh, such a stupid thing to miss, thank you so much!! :))