# Delete button next to every row

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've got this script where users can see a table of projects. But only the admin can delete said projects.

```
$query = ("select * from projectlist");
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    echo "<tr>";
        while( list($key, $value) = each($row)){
            //Print value
            echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
        }

        if($_SESSION['rights'] == 'administrator'){
            echo "<td><i class='fa fa-times-circle-o'></i></td>";
        }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Every row has an id called `projectid`, which get called with the `$query = ("select * from projectlist");`.

You can see that if the admin is logged in, there will be an icon displayed. What I want it to do is that if the user clicks on the icon, the row will be deleted. I'm not really good with php, it took me a while only to get this script working.

If anyobody can help me with this, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Send that link to a new file which executes a query (after proper validation) similar to `DELETE FROM projectlist WHERE id = 2 ` . Of course that 2 and your field names will be replaced with the actual ones

Comment: You likely want to use AJAX for this

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky I saw this question this morning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191026/php-delete-button-for-each-table-row where he uses an hidden input field. Should I do something like this as well?

Comment: @mplungjan I've tried AJAX for another function. But I find it really difficult to understand. Do you perhaps know a way?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$query = ("select * from projectlist");
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
echo "<tr>";
    while( list($key, $value) = each($row)){
        //Print value
        echo "<td>" . $value . "</td><td id='del".$value."'><button></button></td>";
    }

    if($_SESSION['rights'] == 'administrator'){
        echo "<td><i class='fa fa-times-circle-o'></i></td>";
    }
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: This places a button next to every `td` in the entire table. That's why I placed my current delete icon below. As the final `td`. How would this work  anyway?

Comment: where you want to place...?

Comment: 'if($_SESSION['rights'] == 'administrator')', it places an `td` there to go at the end of the table

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)` you can use `mysql_fetch_array($result)`

```
$query = ("select * from projectlist");
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $id = $result['id']; // you unique column in table

  $col1 = $result['col1']; //similarly all other columns

    echo "<td>$col1</td>"; 
    if($_SESSION['rights'] == 'administrator'){
        echo "<td><a href='your_current_page.php?id=$id'><i class='fa fa-times-circle-o'></i></a></td>";
    }
echo "</tr>";
   }
```

Code To Delete Row

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
 {
    $id= $_GET['id'];
    mysql_query("delete from table where id='$id'");
    echo "deleted";//whatever you want to do
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is not complicated at all.

I prefer jQuery when I need Ajax:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(function() { // when page loded
    $(".del").on("click",function(e) { // clicking on a class=del thing
      e.preventDefault(); // stop any submission from the button
      $.post("delete.php",{ "id":$(this).val()},function(data) {
       $("#somemessageDiv").html(data);
      });
    });
  );
</script>
```

using class instead of ID since ID must be unique

```
echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
if($_SESSION['rights'] == 'administrator'){
  echo "<td><button class='del' value='".value."'>DELETE</button></td>";
}
```

Now you need delete.php to take an id and return success or error

Comment: I've got some jquery knowledge, but no ajax. This looks pretty good. But how would I parse the id from the database to the button though?

Comment: That I expected you could handle. Sorry not on my pic

Answer (score 0):

- Create a form for delete particular row.
- Create one hidden field with value will be id of that row.
- Create one deleterow.php and write code for delete that row from database using delete query of mysql.

```
if($_SESSION['rights'] == 'administrator') {
    <form type='post' action ='deleterow.php'>
        <input type="hidden" name='rowid' value='<?php echo $rowid ;?>' />
        echo "<td><input type='submit' name="submit" value="delete" /></td>";
    </form>
}
```